# liquibase defaultValue vs defaultValueNumeric

Tags: liquibase

Can anyone tell me the difference between specifying a defaultValue="0" vs a defaultValueNumeric="0" in a changeset? It's for a bigint column.

http://www.liquibase.org/manual/add_default_value doesn't really go into detail here.

Comment: FWIW I used defaultValueNumeric and it seems to have worked just fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference is that defaultValue puts quotes around the value in the resulting SQL. Many database will interpret inserting '42' into a numeric field as the number 42, but some fail. defaultValueNumeric tells liquibase it is a number and therefore will not be quoted and will work on all database types.

Comment: How does one represent the NULL character in XML / string to be correctly interpreted by liquibase? defaultValue="NULL" ?? Doesn't seem correct as it seems ambigous with defaultValue="Text" in terms of notation.

Comment: @anon58192932 null is the default value if you don't put any